# Overwrite normalizeHttpError in Spartacus

Tags: angular, typescript, spartacus-storefront

I need to overwrite / patch the function `normalizeHttpError` (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop-6.6.x/projects/core/src/util/normalize-http-error.ts) from Spartacus. The function is used inside Spartacus and removes custom data from the body of the http error response. I want to patch the function so that the information is kept. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to overwrite the function in a way that Spartacus internal code uses my patched version too.

The project is built from the Spartacus libraries explained here: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/cfcf687ce2544bba9799aa6c8314ecd0/5de67850bd8d487181fef9c9ba59a31d.html?locale=en-US

What I tried so far is to create a new file and import it in the main.ts file.
I also tried other ways but all without success.

```js
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http'

import { HttpErrorModel, LoggerService, normalizeHttpError as originalNormalizeHttpError } from '@spartacus/core'

export function customNormalizeHttpError(
  error: HttpErrorResponse | HttpErrorModel | unknown,
  logger?: LoggerService,
): HttpErrorModel | undefined {
  console.log('customNormalizeHttpError')
  return originalNormalizeHttpError(error, logger)
}

originalNormalizeHttpError.prototype = customNormalizeHttpError
```

```js
import './app/spartacus/core/utils/normalize-http-error-overwrite.ts'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module'
import { environment } from './environments/environment'

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode()
}

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Does anyone have an idea or hint?

Best regards,
Philipp